Angular TabMenu - no active tab after redirect
I have a tab menu with different urls. I have some case when I need to redirect to the same component, but url is changed. MatTab has no active tab after redirect.
I have routing:
{
    path: 'parent',
    component: EditComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'new',
            component: TabOneComponent,
            resolve: {
                jobOffer: myResolver
            }
        },
        {
            path: ':id/tab-one',
            component: TabOneComponent,
            resolve: {
                jobOffer: myResolver
            }
        },
        {
            path: ':id/tab-two',
            component: TabTwoComponent,
            resolve: {
                jobOffer: myResolver
            }
        },

TabMenuComponent
@Component({
    standalone: true,
    imports: [MatTabsModule, RouterModule, NgFor],
    selector: 'tab-menu',
    templateUrl: './tab-menu.component.html',
})
export class TabMenuComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    @Input() navLinks: ITabMenuElement[];
    @Input() disableWithoutId: boolean;
    @Input() withoutId: boolean = false;
    id = this.activatedRouter.snapshot.children[0].params['id'];
    hasId: boolean = !this.id;
    subscriptionManager = new Subscription();

    constructor(
        private activatedRouter: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscriptionManager.add(
            this.router.events
                .pipe(
                    filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
                )
                .subscribe(event => {
                    this.id = this.activatedRouter.snapshot.children[0].params['id'];
                    this.hasId = !this.id;
                })
        );
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscriptionManager.unsubscribe();
    }

    next(link: string): string {
        if (this.withoutId) {
            return link;
        }

        if (!this.id) {
            return 'new';
        }

        return this.id + '/' + link;
    }

    isActive(rla) {
        return rla.isActive;
    }

    isDisabled(index: number): boolean {
        if (!this.disableWithoutId) {
            return false;
        }

        return index !== 0 && this.hasId;
    }
}

html
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar [tabPanel]="tabPanel" class="mb-5">
    <a
            mat-tab-link
            *ngFor="let link of navLinks; let  i = index"
            [disabled]="isDisabled(i)"
            [routerLink]="next(link.url)"
            routerLinkActive
            #rla="routerLinkActive"
            [active]="isActive(rla)">
        {{ link.label }}
    </a>
</nav>
<mat-tab-nav-panel #tabPanel></mat-tab-nav-panel>

EditComponent
export class EditComponent {
    menuElements: ITabMenuElement[] = [
        {
            label: 'Tab One',
            url: 'tab-one'
        },
        {
            label: 'Tab Two',
            url: 'tab-two'
        }
    ];
}

html
<div>
    <tab-menu [navLinks]="menuElements" [disableWithoutId]="true"></tab-menu>
    <div>
        <div>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

In TabOneComponent and TabTwoComponent i have forms.
There is one case when I need to redirect from tab-one to tab-one, exactly from "parent/new" to "parent/:id/tab-one. Just like this
this.router.navigate(['parent', id, 'tab-one']);

and there is no active tab.
Redirecting to tab-two works fine.
I will be grateful for any help.
